# Where to find data sets for testing minimum vertex cover algorithm for bipartite graphs?

Tags: data-sets, graph-theory

I'm playing with simple implementations of algorithms to find minimum vertex cover/maximum cardinality matching in bipartite graphs. However, I seem to have trouble googling for some test data sets that I could use to verify, if I got that one right.

It's easy to devise simple examples that one could check on paper, but I'd hope for some larger/tricky benchmarks.

I'm asking because I do remember from my research that you can find such benchmark data for machine learning problems, for example.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There's benchmark code for max cardinality matching](http://www.avglab.com/andrew/soft.html): you could use that and even randomly generated bipartite graphs to establish ground truth and test out your algorithms.